# Namespacing the Bootstrap and Foundation CSS frameworks

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, namespaces, zurb-foundation

I'm injecting the [Foundation CSS framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) into an existing project. Many of Foundation's class names conflict with classes in the underlying code. How can I encapsulate the Foundation JavaScript and CSS files in their own namespace?

These are the specific files that cause the conflicts:

- [foundation.css](http://dpaste.com/3WCKER1)
- [foundation.js](http://dpaste.com/22RR7SY)
- [foundation.reveal.js](http://dpaste.com/2ZZNA30)

I'm using Foundation v5.

I've added the `twitter-bootstrap` tag to this question because I've also tried to put the Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript files in their own namespace (e.g., with [these instructions](http://longtermcache.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-prefix-to-bootstrap-css-classes.html)), but with no success. I suspect that the right namespacing approach would work for both Foundation and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up swapping Foundation for the [Ink framework](https://github.com/sapo/Ink/), which has the features I need and also namespaces most of its classes. I realize that this doesn't directly answer the question, but it solved my problem, so I'm posting it in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only option i see is to edit the sass files of foundation  and compile your own version.

There is a discussion on github related to this issue:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/546

Maybe it's easier to prefix your own classes instead of the framework ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think prefixing the classes breaks the JavaScript libraries.