# How can i avoid conflicts of two css frameworks?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation CSS framework and Kendo UI grid in my project The Kendo UI grid sometimes overridden by foundation CSS thing.

How can I avoid this conflicts?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Why @Paulie_D is this question not worthy to ask . I dont' think so

Comment: Because it's too broad IMO...Other opinions might vary. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."

Comment: @Pauline_D  how would you rephrase this question better, just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think there is a way that you can do this. A browser will load all stylesheets in the order they are placed on your page. When there are selectors that is used in more stylesheets, the last occurrence takes precedence (meaning: it's the one that your browser will use).

You can add a third stylesheet in which you fix everything that gets overwritten by mistake, or you can try switching the Foundation css and the kendo grid UI css

Comment: This is disappointing that no features available to avoid the conflicts.Anyway  I ll try your idea and let you know how it works @steven Lemmens

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is namespacing. As far as I'm aware there's no built in way to do this, but the question has been asked before:

- [Namespacing the Bootstrap and Foundation CSS frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618627/namespacing-the-bootstrap-and-foundation-css-frameworks)

Comment: The other question never provided an answer.  I don't think "just switch to another framework" is a good enough answer.

Comment: @Novina Even I got the same suggestion what steven lemmens provided from my colleagues. override the same class/id in third css so that browser takes the last values.